# Add the r script to power bi

Tags: powerbi

I would like to add the below r script to power bi and then where I have time_tot I want to be able to replace that value by a measure from Power BI and so on for `num_rev` to. and then populate the results into a table in power bi.

internet research and blogs

````
num_rev <- 18
(incidence <- (num_rev/time_tot)*100)
(ci <- (unlist(prop.test(num_rev,time_tot)[6])*100))```

as described above in the question. the ability to populate results into a table visual.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is an extension in the PowerBI-Desktop for R. You can installit. The only thing you have to keep in mind is that all output must be a graphical object somehow. So just datatables are not allowed as outcome, because you cannot display them.

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/power-bi/desktop-r-visuals

Comment: ok thanks for the feedback, question can i reproduce that R code in power bi using a measure?

Comment: significance tests are not part of PowerBI right now, try to solve it with R, https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Can-Power-BI-Visualize-Significance-Testing-in-a-Table-form/td-p/61501

Comment: R is not my strong point, still learning.. happy to describe the solution with sample data?

Comment: PV*. Many thanks for the positive feedback, much appreciated.

Comment: sorry but I am also not into R

Answer (score 0):

Once your table has loaded into PowerBi, in Power Query, duplicate this table and click on Transform and on the icon (you must have R installed on your computer) :

[image]

A window opens:
[image]

Leave the first row, your table is now called dataset.
You can make a copy :

```
myTable <- dataset
```

And carry out your operations on your data.frame, for example add a column :

```
myTable$newColonne <- 1
myTable$newColonne2 <- myTable$newColonne + 1
```

In your case if in the table there are the num_rev field and the time_tot field, you can create an incidence column:

```
myTable$incidence <- (myTable$num_rev/ myTable$time_tot)*100
```

At the end, delete anything you don't want to keep (especially constants and other data.frame):

```
rm(list=setdiff(ls(), " myTable "))
```

click ok, then click [image]